# Some confusing points about Bell's spaceship paradox from a video

Tags: special-relativity, acceleration, observers, string

I was looking this video about Bell's Spaceship Paradox on Youtube titled [*This Paradox Took 17 Years To Solve. It's Still Debated*](https://youtu.be/PO4a2zO8zW8?t=517). Please note that the video starts at the segment I have a question about.

The capture below from the video shows the setup.

[image]

**Introduction from the video's transcript**: *Consider the following scenario: Two spaceships connected by a taut string are accelerating in exactly the same fashion. What happens to the string? Does it snap? If the acceleration is the same, then the distance between them should also remain the same. So the string should not snap, right? But if they accelerate anywhere near the speed of light, length contraction happens. So snap? But the spaceships don't observe the length contraction and neither does the string. So which is it? Does it snap or not? We can solve this, but it's going to test the limits of special relativity.*

**Personal opinion**: I'm only interested how Charles interprets the situation because I personally find it more understandable and 'real'. If Arthur and Bernard are so advanced to have developed such spaceships then they should also know that what's really going on rather than thinking if one is lagging behind or other is going too fast!

Please try to avoid concepts such as worldlines etc. and try to keep it as simple and as intuitive as possible. I'm trying to look at it in terms of dynamic interpretation of special relativity and not kinematic.

**Why string breaks for Charles from the video's transcript**:
*At the beginning, everyone is stationary relative to each other, so they're all in the same frame of reference. Having the rockets start at the same moment isn't the problem. It's the acceleration rate that's the problem. There's only one observer that measures those rates to be the same: Charles.*

*... Since they accelerate at the same rate... The rockets maintain a steady distance from each other while contracting in length. But the string is attached to both ships, so it can't contract even though it's trying to. The extra tension makes it snap.*

**Question 1**:

Around 3:21 into the video the length contraction for rockets is shown as if the rockets are contracting toward their center point from both forward and backward directions as shown below in the picture. The string is also shown to snap from the middle. I agree that it's just an animation to convey a general idea and doesn't need to be accurate. I understand that length contraction is independent of the material an object is made up of. In dynamic interpretation of special relativity, how does the length contraction really happen? Does it happen toward the center point as shown in the picture below, or toward backward point?

[image]

**Question 2**:

Around 8:57 into the video, the following is said. *"Yet another assumption we've made here is that the string is incredibly weak. It has no effect on how the rockets move. Technically, this string breaks immediately. You could easily choose something stronger, like a thick metal rod or something. But the stronger it is, the more it will affect how the rockets move. If it's strong enough, the rockets won't even be independent anymore. Arthur will just be towing Bernard. They'll act as one object"*. Will Charles also see Arthur towing Bernard when a thick metal rod is used instead of an incredibly weak string? How would Charles interpret the situation if he, in fact, sees Arthur towing Bernard?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: There is no contraction in the rest frame of A & B, so nothing happens. From C's point of view: It doesn't matter. Charlie needs to define a reference point, and if he chooses the front of the rocket or the back: it doesn't matter. If he picks the tip of the nose, then the tail "catches up" as it contracts. If he picks the middle then the nose and tail crunch in. And so on.  Note that it is not like a spring, as no stresses are accumulated during contraction.

Question 2: If the string is super strong, then it can be compensated by thrust so that A & B remain on their trajectory. It *will* break, though, eventually.  If the rocket thrust can't do that, then A & B fail to follow the proper trajectory proscribed in the problem. Whether A tows B forward or B pulls A back doesn't really matter. They're pulling each other and no longer accelerate uniformly in C's frame.

Comment: Thank you! Re Q1. There are two rockets and a  string. Doesn't Charles need to be consistent with how he defines the reference point? If he picks the tip of one rocket, doesn't he need to do the same for other rocket and string? I think Charles cannot choose tips for the rockets and the middle point for the string.

Comment: @PG1995 Charles really can only pick one point, says the tip of rocket B, and defines the Lorentz transform  (LT) from C to the rockets' frame. The LT will then push A forward and stretch the B rocket from behind. If you really want the answers: Do the LTs of all the noses and tails of rockets and it will be clear.

Comment: Thank you! You said, *"The LT will then push A forward and stretch the B rocket from behind"*. I think that you are saying that the transform is from Charles frame of reference and Charles can only choose one reference point for the entire setup which consists of two rockets and a string. Wouldn't pushing setup from front and stretching from behind make the setup look elongated rather than contracted? Please have a look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Sdc.png. Also, I agree with you that math can give the final answer but I'm looking for intuitive understanding and I've basic understanding.

Comment: @PG1995 that's the whole point of the paradox: rockets A & B move apart.

Comment: Thank you! But rockets A and B get only length contracted in Charles frame? Is the length contraction equivalent to the moving apart? For example, around 7:30 into the video this is said: *There's only one observer that measures those rates to be the same: Charles. For him, ... rockets maintain a steady distance from each other while contracting in length. But the string is attached to both ships, so it can't contract even though it's trying to. The extra tension makes it snap*. I'm only interested in Charles viewpoint. Also, I think I better edit the main question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The apparent paradox- as with the twin paradox and the pole-in-the-barn paradox- is the result of the relativity of simultaneity, and arises from the ambiguity of the phrase 'accelerating in exactly the same fashion'. What you have to remember is that the spaceships can only accelerate 'in exactly the same fashion' in one reference frame, because in any other frame their instantaneous changes in velocity won't be simultaneous. So if they start accelerating simultaneously in a ground frame, then as they speed up their accelerations will get more and more out of synch, the distance between them will increase and the string will break.

Comment: Thank you. You said, *"...then as they speed up their accelerations will get more and more out of synch, the distance between them will increase and the string will break...*. But in the ground frame, the reference frame of Charles, the distance between them remains constant and won't get out of sync? Could you please confirm?

Comment: @PG1995 yes that's right. If the accelerating spaceships tried to remain a fixed distance apart in their own frame (ie if they did not break the string) that distance would become progressively shorter in the ground frame owing to length contraction. So the only way to maintain their spacing in the ground frame is to move further apart in their own frame, which breaks the string.

Comment: Thank you! Around 7:30 into the video this is said: *There's only one observer that measures those rates to be the same: Charles. For him, ... rockets **maintain a steady distance from each other while contracting in length**. But the string is attached to both ships, so it can't contract even though it's trying to. The extra tension makes it snap*. Not sure if I'm splitting hairs but if they are contracting while accelerating, the distance between them would increase in proportion to the contraction. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: Don't forget that length contraction is a property of spacetime, not just of physical objects. It is the actual distance in space that contracts, whether or not there are physical objects present. Think of this another way. Suppose you ask two people to hold either end of a 100m long string. You then accelerate past them and ask them to remain exactly 100m apart in your frame. As you go faster, 100m in the ground frame contracts, so to remain 100m apart in your frame the two people have to move further apart so the string they hold will break.

Comment: Thank you! You said, *"Don't forget that length contraction is a property of spacetime, not just of physical objects. It is the actual distance in space that contracts, whether or not there are physical objects present."* IMHO, the distance becomes shorter from the perspective of someone X who is travelling close to the speed of light. However, from the perspective of someone Y stationary, the distance remains the same but clock for X is running slow so X registers short distance. I've always thought, from dynamic approach to SR, length contraction, time dilation, and **cont'd**

Comment: mass increase are real. That's more along the line of dynamic approach to SR. (I understand the concepts of mass increase or relative mass are not really correct.) Also, I'm more interested in how a stationary observer looks at the situation.

Answer (score 0):

The analysis in terms of proper acceleration is wrong because of Hooke's Law. The length of rope in  the inertial frame can't be constant when the proper accelerations are constant.

The rope isn't Born rigid. It merely has to satisfy Hooke's Law. Then the rope will stretch, slowing down  down the leading ship and speeding up the trailing ship.

Each rocket will have an inertial guidance system, Inertial guidance systems have both an accelerometer and a gyrocompass. The accelerometer measures proper acceleration.

So the two ships don't have to communicate with each other to maintain constant acceleration. The proper accelerations won't ever go out of synch because both accelerometers are working independently.

Suppose one ship is being towed by the other ship. Suppose that the rocket thrust and the rest mass of both ships are constant.

The astronauts in each space ship have to wait till the transients damp out by friction. But if they do wait for equilibrium, then they adjust their thrusts so each proper acceleration is held constant.

$$m_0 a_1 = F_R − F_T $$
$$m_0 a_2 = F_R + F_T $$

where $F_T$ is the proper thrust force, $F_T$ is the proper tension, $a_1$ is the proper acceleration of the leading ship and $a_2$ is the proper acceleration of the trailing ship.

Then,

$$ F_R = 0.5 m_0 (a_1 + a_2) $$
$$ F_T = 0.5 m_0 (a_1 − a_2) $$

Hooke's law is

$$ K \Delta L = F_T $$

If the two proper accelerations are precisely the same ($a_1 = a_2$), then the tension on the rope will be zero ($F_T = 0$). The ship in the frame of either astronaut remains constant.

But the length of the rope as measured in an inertial frame is going to shrink according to the Lorentz length contraction formula. The inertial frame will also see the two space ships accelerate together, both approaching the speed of light, $c$, asymptotically.

The inertial frame length is shrinking due to relativity but it is expanding due to the tension.

If the the leading value of proper acceleration is larger than the proper acceleration of the trailing ship ($a_1>a_2$), then the tension is nonzero ($F_T>0$).

So the rope will start to stretch  and vibrate in the astronaut frame. But the vibrations in a real material will eventually damp out due to internal friction.

You can redo these equations using more complicated hypotheses for the material. But in all variation, a strong rope can tow the trailing space ship. If the trailing space ship is towed, then the rest length increases because the rope stretches.

Please note that the proper acceleration is the ONLY acceleration an astronaut can hope to measure directly. He keeps the proper acceleration constant using his inertial guidance system.

So the thread does NOT have to be infinitely fragile as Bell stated. a strong thread can tow the space ship.

I know my explanation is a bit of a stretch !-)

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1:

Question is unanswerable, like the question "does a rubber band stretch away from the center, or away from the left end, or away from the right end?"

Answer to question 2:

The rod steals kinetic energy from one ship and gives kinetic energy to other ship. This can be called towing.

Such towing where first the towed accelerates and moves faster than the tower, but later the towed still moves very slightly faster, but accelerates slower than the towed. This way the towed does not overtake the tower, which would be quite odd.